# X Many-to-many relation with Y - How to get all X that have all defined Y properties

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Company has a many-to-many relation with Industry type. That is, a company can have many industry types and an industry type can be assigned to many companies.

An IEnumerable (called industryTypes) is passed to a method which should return an IEnumerable. These companies must fulfill the following rules:

- Returned companies must have all industryTypeNames from the input.
- Returned companies can have more industry types than the input defines, but all of the ones defined by the input must exist.

I tried many different ways, but i saved this ones to have examples:

```
var industryTypeNames = industryTypes.Select(x => x.Name).Distinct();
```

The whole structure does not really matter. All mappings are working.

The classes have:

```
public class Company
{
    Guid Id;
    IList<IndustryType> IndustryTypes;
}

public class IndustryType
{
    Guid Id;
    string Name;
    IList<Company> Companies;
}
```

Mappings work fine. The issue is regarding the query.

Here are implementations which are NOT working:

```
       Company companyAlias = null;
       var query = Session.QueryOver<IndustryType>()
                            .WhereRestrictionOn(dbIndustryType => dbIndustryType.Name).IsIn(industryTypeNames)
                            .JoinAlias(dbIndustryType => dbIndustryType.Companies, () => companyAlias)
                            .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count(() => companyAlias.Id), industryTypeNames.Length))
                            .Select(Projections.Group(() => companyAlias));
```

Another one:

```
        IndustryType industryTypeAlias = null;
        var query = Session.QueryOver<Company>()
                            .JoinAlias(dbCompany => dbCompany.IndustryTypes, () => industryTypeAlias)
                            .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count(() => industryTypeAlias.Id), industryTypeNames.Length))
                            .WhereRestrictionOn(() => industryTypeAlias.Name).IsIn(industryTypeNames);
```

Comment: Looks like you are wanting to preserve this as an answer for yourself, right?  I.e., you already have the answer to your question.  In that case, you might want to split this into a question and post what you found out as your own answer to your question. It's ok to do that, and it sticks to the Q and A format of StackOverflow.  Right now, you're answer is part of your question, which does not stick to the format.

Comment: @DWright Those are not answers, are examples of wrong implementations I have tried. I have just updated it to make sure its clear. I don't know the answer yet. I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I hadn't fully understood.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I have separated the query into 2 parts. It isn't the most efficient way, but I need to read NHibernate documentation to learn how to it more efficiently.

The current query:

```
        var query = Session.QueryOver<Company>()
                                .JoinAlias(dbCompany => dbCompany.IndustryTypes, () => industryTypeAlias)
                                .WhereRestrictionOn(() => industryTypeAlias.Name).IsIn(industryTypeNames)
                                .SelectList(list => list
                                                        .SelectGroup(dbCompany => dbCompany.Id)
                                                        .SelectCount(dbCompany => industryTypeAlias.Name))
                                .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count<Company>(dbCompany => industryTypeAlias.Name), industryTypeNames.Length))
                                .SelectList(list => list
                                                        .SelectGroup(dbCompany => dbCompany.Id).WithAlias(() => resIndustryType.Id)
                                           )
                                .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<DtoCompany>());

        var resultCompanyIdList = query.List().Select(company => company.Id).ToArray();

        var result = Session.QueryOver<DtoCompany>()
                                .WhereRestrictionOn(dbCompany => dbCompany.Id)
                                .IsIn(resultCompanyIdList);

        return result.List();
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure may not matter, but the mappings DO!
Creating a many-to-many relationship involves the creation of an in-the-middle table to map keys from both tables. In Nhibernate you do it like this

```
public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
{
    public CompanyMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x => x.IndustryTypes)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Table("CompaniesIndustryTypes");
    }
}

public class IndustryTypeMap : ClassMap<IndustryType>
{
    public IndustryTypeMap()
    {
        HasManyToMany(x => x.Companies)
           .Cascade.All()
           .Inverse()
           .Table("CompaniesIndustryTypes");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is already done. The mappings work fine. The issue is with the query.